# How to get information from a namespace polluted memory dump, using windbg "dt" command

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg, dump, debug-symbols

I'm investigatin a memory dump, using `windbg`. It contains lots of entries, which I like to investigate (using `windbg` `dt` command), but this seems to be failing:

About the symbols:

```
0:000> x /2 <product_name>!<company>::<main_product>::<chapter>::<subchapter>::<Current_Object>*
01251194 <product_name>!<company>::<main_product>::<chapter>::<subchapter>::<Current_Object>::`vftable'
0125115c <product_name>!<company>::<main_product>::<chapter>::<subchapter>::<Current_Object>::`vftable'
```

=> the objects are known by the symbols. (the `.sympath` is correct)

```
dt <product_name>!<company>::<main_product>::<chapter>::<subchapter>::<Current_Object>::`vftable' <memory_address>
=> symbol <product_name>!<company>::<main_product>::<chapter>::<subchapter>::<Current_Object> not found
```

For your information: I've tried with/without `<product_name>`, with/without `::` at the end, with/without the whole namespace entries, ...

=> How can I get `windbg` `dt` to work, while working with namespace preceeded types?

Comment: Doesn't `dt` work the other way round? `dt <type> <address>`

Comment: @ThomasWeller: sorry, that was a typo, I solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some weird reason, this seems not to work using Windbg, but using Windbg preview it works. (Just for your information, I've checked both symbol paths, they are equal)